# Find the value of the determinant:

Tags: matrices

The value of the determinant :
$$
W=\left (\begin{array}{cccc}
1&w&w^2 \\
w&w^2&1 \\
w^2&1&w
\end{array}\right),
$$.

My Attempt:

Expanding through $R_1$.
$$=1(w^3-1)-w(w^2-w^2)+w^2(w-w^4)$$
$$=w^3-1+w^3-w^6$$
$$=2w^3-w^6-1$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: That's it. You have solved the question.

Comment: I guess you could express it as $-(w^3-1)^2$, but that's about it

Comment: If you have $w$ as a cubic root of unity, then it further simplifies to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually $w^3=w^6=1$ (If $w$ is cube root of unity)

thus you can simplify it further to get $0$